# Disable torch shortcut

Tags: miui

The Redmi Note / MIUI has an in-built feature that enables the torch on home button long press (~3 sec) even when the device is in locked state

http://c.mi.com/thread-171963-1-0.html

I tried a number settings and solutions to disable this feature but with no success. Is there a way in which this can be disabled?

**Edit 1:**

Upon checking on devices other than MI too the same functionality is noticed.

Comment: I have not scene this on my redmi 1s or note 4. I always keep recents on my home/Longpress. From settings buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this functionality cannot be disabled on Xioami phones.